# generate pdf from tabulated records in php

Tags: php, pdf

I want to generate the pdf file from the below code,my code returns the employee commission report.I want to show that record in pdf format.I'm using **phptopdf API**

I can generate it but in intermediately I'm having **while loop** so I can not store my desired format in a variable with the php code inside my structure.

```
<table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                           <thead>
                           <tr>
                           <th>Date</th>
                           <th>Employee Name</th>
                           <th>Employee Code</th>
                           <th>Commission Amount</th>
                           </tr>
                           </thead>

                <?php   
                if(isset($_POST['submit']))
                {  
                  extract($_POST);
                  $con='';
                  if($fromdate!='' && $todate!=''){ $con .="AND `credit_date` BETWEEN '$fromdate' AND '$todate'";}
                  else{ $con .="";}
                 $agent_commissions="SELECT * FROM commission_details WHERE `emp_code`='".$emp_code."'".$con;
                 //echo $agent_commissions."<br>";
                 $get_all=mysql_query($agent_commissions);
                 $row_count=mysql_num_rows($get_all);
                 if($row_count == 0){echo "<h3 class='msyqlerror'>No records found<h3>";exit(0);}

                 $total_amnt="";
                     while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($get_all))
                     {
                        // echo $rows['comm_amount']."<br>";
                         $total_amnt = $total_amnt+$rows['comm_amount'];

                ?>
```

Kindly help me to solve this:(

```
                <td><?php echo $rows['credit_date'];?></td>
                <td>
                    <?php
                      $get_name="SELECT e1.emp_name,e1.emp_code,c1.emp_code FROM emp_details e1,commission_details c1 WHERE e1.emp_code = '".$emp_code."'";
                     // echo $get_name;
                      $exe_name=mysql_query($get_name);
                      $name_fetch=mysql_fetch_array($exe_name);
                      echo $name_fetch['emp_name'];
                    ?>
                </td>
                <td><?php echo $rows['emp_code'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $rows['comm_amount'];?></td>
                <?php 
                    }?>
                    <tr>
                      <td colspan=3 align="right">Total</td>
                      <td> <?php  echo $total_amnt;
                }
                ?></td>
                    </tr>

             </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a tutorial that will give you brief description about PDF,

http://www.code2learn.com/2012/03/generating-tabulated-pdf-file-from.html

Comment: I have referred this link..that is for code igniter im asking for core php.

Comment: If you want pdf for core php you have to use binary from this site,

http://www.fpdf.org/

Comment: where do i get fpdf.php

Comment: Hope this solve your issue, make a thumb up if this helps you.

Comment: I have done it...But if i have any doubts pls reply me

Comment: I want to get the results from commission.php file.So may i add the commission.php instead of countries.txt in http://www.fpdf.org/en/tutorial/tuto5.htm

Comment: Ye you can, but then you have to customize `LoadData` function

Comment: How to do that?can u pls explain it

Comment: as you can see that in tutorial 5 it is passing a file to function LoadData,

`function LoadData($file)
{
    // Read file lines
    $lines = file($file);
    $data = array();
    foreach($lines as $line)
        $data[] = explode(';',trim($line));
    return $data;
}`

Now if you use `commission.php` then you also have to customize your logic to get your file data in `data` array.

Comment: im having "download pdf" button.That is linked with that file.But when i click it it does not return anything

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used phptopdf API  but i think you can store all date in variable and then can pass that variable to pdf function .

Comment: Before this I did as you said..But now i want to fetch the all commission amount records for an employee so in that case i need to put while to fetch that.i can not use while when trying to store that in a variable

Comment: Yes , you can call all your code as it is ( even while code )  but save it in variable only ( using concatenation  ) and then pass it in pdf function.